# Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - but the program still executes correctly?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a program that outputs a histogram based on

- User input regarding how many lines the histogram should be, and
- the actual numbers (which are also user input)

The program works fine, EXCEPT that I get the message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>     at test.Test.main(Test.java:32)
>   /Users/[myname]/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)

when the program has finished. What is the problem?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String star = "*";
        int index = 1;

        System.out.println("How many lines?");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your histogram will be "+ num +" lines");
        int[] histogram = new int[num];

        for (int i = 0; i < histogram.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Please write number " + index++);

            histogram[i] = input.nextInt();

        }

        System.out.println("Here is your histogram: ");           

        for (int i = 0; 1 < histogram.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < histogram[i]; j++)

            System.out.print(star);
            System.out.println();

        }

    System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; 1 < histogram.length; i++) {`, did you mean `for (int i = 0; i < histogram.length; i++) {` ?

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
for (int i = 0; 1 < histogram.length; i++) {
```

by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < histogram.length; i++) {
```

Otherwise, it will execute the correct number of times (since `i` is still incremented, and the inner loop loops up till `i`) and crash when it reaches "OutofBounds", but since the loop is at the end of your program it looks like it executes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you wrote `1 < histogram.length` when you actually mean `i < histogram.length`.

If you don't know where I'm referring to, here it is:

```
    System.out.println("Here is your histogram: ");           

    for (int i = 0; 1 < histogram.length; i++) { // <-- this line right here
        for (int j = 0; j < histogram[i]; j++)

        System.out.print(star);
        System.out.println();

    }
```

`1 < histogram.length` causes the loop to never end. Therefore, after it printed all the histogram rows, `i` increments and it exceeds the size of the array. Since all the things that you wanted it to print have been printed at this point, it seems like you get the correct output.

Basically, a program will keep printing things *until* there is an exception or the end of the program is reached. The presence of an exception does not make the whole program output nothing.